# Red Black Tree`s leaf version

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

> Given a red black tree . Transform the given RBT into an RBT where the keys of the orginal tree are stored in the leafs and the interior nodes store additional keys such that all the interior nodes satisfy the binary tree search property with respect to their keys

Can someone give me a hint how one can transform any RBT into the leaf version of that RBT ?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: You should probably clarify what you mean by "all the information is stored in the interior nodes", because it looks like you're changing the definition of "interior" in the middle of your question.  In any case, though, the solution will probably rely on the fact that when all interior nodes have 2 children, then an in-order traversal alternates between leaf node and interior node on every step.

Comment: @MattTimmermans : By "all the information" I mean all the keys of the orginal RBT. I will edit my text above and hope that this makes it easier to understand

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but note that there are generally (about) as many leafs as there are internal nodes. I *think* you should be able to do the transformation by adding a leaf version of each node on the right side of the descendant predecessor node (the highest-valued descendant of lower value, which is always a right-leaf), or if none exists (the original node is a left-leaf), add that leaf version as left child.